# Terrain rendering on mobile device

Tags: scenekit

I have downloaded NASA SRTM files. Each files contains about 4000x4000 points. Each point value is altimetry. Gap between points is about 90m. We know GPS coordinates of corners point corresponding to file.

I want do display terrain on a phone screen. I have tried OpenGL and scenekit (iOS), but it is very slow to load vertex.
I have about 2000x2000 Points. I create 2 triangles per square. It is not very big but it is very slow to load those points in OpenGL buffers (idem for scenekit).
I am wondering how are working games like GTA because i think they have a big number of vertex and it is not very slow...

Any idea to speed up vertex loading ?

Thanks

Comment: what's your definition of slow, and what conversions of the point information are you doing in order to localise them to the scenekit world?

Comment: Did you see any improvement using the suggestions I made in my answer to your other question on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938464/big-scngeometry-scenekit-for-ios